# Is there a general H-theorem?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

In statistical mechanics, Boltzmann showed that for dilute gases the H-function increases. I remember from a lecture that there is no general [H-theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-theorem), e.g. for non-dilute gases or in the quantum case but there seem to be also claims to the contrary. So what is the status of the (generalised) H-theorem?

Comment: Boltzmann has shown his $H$ function *decreases* in time (under certain assumptions).

Comment: @JánLalinský - I thought Boltzmann defined _a priori_ the $H$-function to decrease because it corresponded to the physical "direction" of time?

Comment: @honeste_vivere, no, why do you think that? $H$ function is defined as functional of probability distribution. It decreases in some situations and increases in other.

Comment: @JánLalinský - I recall reading it in one of Cedric Villani's books and several others.  Boltzmann was criticized by some other big name for doing this and his response was for them to propose a situation where $H$ would change in the opposite sense.  I forget now but I definitely recall reading something along these lines.